# How to find cause of failure when list upload through FuelSDK fails

Tags: list, fuel-sdk, import

When my script attempt to import a list that I uploaded via CSV and I check the status, it eventually returns this.  What is the cause of failure?

```
response from ET_Import.status()
ET_Get Object
(
    [status] => 1
    [code] => 200
    [message] => 
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [PartnerKey] => 
                    [ObjectID] => 
                    [ImportDefinitionCustomerKey] => 2016-05-21-5612-1191-5155
                    [StartDate] => 5/21/2016 12:43:34 PM
                    [EndDate] => 5/21/2016 12:43:34 PM
                    [DestinationID] => 535897
                    [NumberSuccessful] => 0
                    [NumberDuplicated] => 0
                    [NumberErrors] => 0
                    [TotalRows] => 0
                    [ImportType] => Subscriber List
                    [ImportStatus] => Error
                    [TaskResultID] => 29937191
                )

        )

    [request_id] => ffea7782-61b5-4c5c-90dc-a98d81f94e72
    [moreResults] => 
)
```